# How to have a folder structure in a wordpress template (For ex : http://www.example.com/products/story)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and trying to get my head around it. I figured that I can create a custom php file  as

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: The Story
*/
?>
<?php get_header() ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <div class="story_content"><?php echo get_option('story-content') ?></div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

and in the admin panel , I can add a new page and choose "the story" as the template , which will in turn , give me an URL as http://www.example.com/thestory

But for the life of me , I can't figure out how to have a directory structure in the website such as http://www.example.com/products/thestory

Can someone help me out here.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with ["Pretty Permalinks"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#mod_rewrite:_.22Pretty_Permalinks.22) enabled in WordPress, by simply creating two pages:

1. A **Products** page with a slug of `/products`
2. A **The Story** page that is a child of **Products** (i.e. **The Story** has a parent post: **Products**). You'd make this slug `/thestory` (it will automatically be appended to the parent slug: `/products`)

This can all be done from within the Dashboard Pages area, without editing templates.

Comment: Works like a charm. Appreciate your help @mevius

Comment: My pleasure! FYI, the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) is a goldmine of good information. Good luck!